# What is the hex value of P1MDOUT in order for p1.3 and p1.5 to be registered as "push-pull" outputs while to the other six pins in port 1 as default?

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, 8051

what hexadecimal value should be written to P1MDOUT in order to configure P1.3 and P1.5 as "push-pull" outputs while leaving the other six pins of Port 1 in their default "open-drain" state? Mind you this is in reference to EFM8BB1

Answer (score 2):

According to the [EFM8BB1 Reference Manual](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/efm8bb1-rm.pdf), each bit of `P1MDOUT` sets the output mode of the corresponding pin of `P1`.

```
P1 pin:      |  7  |  6  |  5  |  4  |  3  |  2  |  1  |  0  |
P1MDOUT bit: |  7  |  6  |  5  |  4  |  3  |  2  |  1  |  0  |
```

It also says that for each bit:

```
Value |     Name   |      Description
  0   | OPEN_DRAIN | pin output is open-drain.
  1   | PUSH_PULL  | pin output is push-pull.
```

So in your case to set `P1.3` and `P1.5` as push-pull and all the other as open drain, you need `P1MDOUT` to have the value:

```
P1 pin:       |  7  |  6  |  5  |  4  |  3  |  2  |  1  |  0  |
P1MDOUT bit:  |  7  |  6  |  5  |  4  |  3  |  2  |  1  |  0  |
P1MDOUT value |  0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0  |
```

The binary value :`0010 1000` is equivalent to `0x28` in hexadecimal, or `40` in decimal.

So your statement, depending on the environment you are coding with, should look like:

```
P1MDOUT = 0x28 ;
```